# How to auto start a winform application programmatically in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows Form Application that has settings, in the settings window I'll have a check box witch indicates that my application should start automatically after windows start-up or not. I need to set and unset this future programmatically in c#. What is the simplest way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To auto-run your program at windows startup you want to add your application to the registry key at:

```
hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

There will be other keys there; take a look in regedit to see examples of what yours needs to look like.

You can add or remove a key there with the registry class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx

Comment: would this approach work for all windows versions? except windows 95 or 98. It is important to work on XP, 2003, 2008 , Vista and 7 both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, that's the officially recommended place to put your startup items.

Answer (score 0):

one option would be http://simpcode.blogspot.com/2008/07/c-set-and-unset-auto-start-for-windows.html